# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: django, django-models, django-errors, django-aggregation

How can I handle this error, its driving me crazy:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Also

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Float' and 'NoneType'
```

I get what its telling me (I think) so this is the code I wrote to try and battle it

View:

```
session = request.session._session_key
ind = signedup.objects.filter(sessionid = session)
team = team_signup.objects.filter(sessionid = session)
combine = list(chain(ind, team))


check = signedup.objects.filter(sessionid = session).count() + team_signup.objects.filter(sessionid = session).count()
ind = signedup.objects.filter(sessionid = session).aggregate(Sum ('price'))['price__sum']
team = team_signup.objects.filter(sessionid = session).aggregate(Sum ('price'))['price__sum']
if check == 0:
  carttotal = 0.00
elif ind == None:
  ind = 0.00
elif team == None:
  team = 0.00

carttotal = ind + team


return render_to_response("cart.html",locals(),context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I figured what I was doing was setting their values to 0 before adding it up if it happened to be come up with none as a value. Is there another way to handle this so that when one of them does come up none, it gets set to zero so it can be added. Also when BOTH come up to none they can be set to  0 so that they can be added.

Comment: First add `print int` and `print team` to see which values are `None`. Also, is this your _Actual_ view? stacktrace + exact code would be helpful

Comment: yes this is my actual view all that comes after is a return. I'm not sure what stack trace is. Also anyone of them could be None because chain is taking values from two queries, they wont always both return something

Comment: stacktrace is what you see on the error screen (which mentions the line number of the issue, etc.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is probably the if/elif logic.  Remember that elif will only run if the first if statement registers as false.  So, imagine this scenario:

```
check = 0
ind = None
team = None
```

In that scenario, the first that that happens is that carttotal gets set equal to 0.  Then, since the first if was true (check was 0), the remaining elifs don't run, and ind + team try get added even though they haven't been changed from None.

There are more elegant ways to do this, but if you just change the elifs to ifs, it should work fine.  There's some redundancy there, though, and shorten the logic to by a few lines by using a tertiary operator

```
ind_query = signedup.objects.filter(sessionid = session)
ind = ind_query.aggregate(Sum ('price'))['price__sum'] if ind_query else 0

team_query = team_signup.objects.filter(sessionid = session)
team = team_query.aggregate(Sum ('price'))['price__sum'] if team_query else 0

carttotal = ind + team
```

Comment: sir , I feel smarter because of you. I wish I had thought to do that instead of what I ended up doing ( creating a dummy instance if it doesnt exist (im still new)). Your way is probably more efficient on the db so I'll use it, thanks. I did not know that elif only happens if , if is false.

Comment: Yeah, elif is Python's shortened way of saying "else, if" -- so the "else" part has to be true (meaning the original if was False) before the second if will even be evaluated.